# Handle back pressed to not dismiss activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I want to handle back press like whatsapp where while typing if user presses back the keyboard is dismissed and if the user presses back again ,we go to chats tab.In my activity I want that when the user presses back while typing the keyboard dismisses and some UI elements are handled.I tried handling that in the onBackPressed() method , but it isn't working and the activity is killed.

```
     edittext.setOnEditorActionListener (
                    new EditText.OnEditorActionListener () {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                                    event != null &&
                                            event.getAction () == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                                            event.getKeyCode () == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                                if (event == null || !event.isShiftPressed ()) {
                                    // the user is done typing.

                                    View view1 = getCurrentFocus ();
                                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow (view1.getWindowToken (), 0);

                                    Log.e (TAG, "TYPING DONE ");
                                    result = tv_result.getText ().toString();

                                    return true; // consume.
                                }
                            }
                            return false; // pass on to other listeners.
                        }
                    }
            );
```

the onBackPressed() code

```
     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    tv_result.setText("Some text");

}
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: Is that view done on Fragments or Activities?

Comment: dismissing keyboard is default behavior of Android, so, to investigate the error, we need to see your code

Comment: @Robert in activity

Comment: @hasbi said right its auto behavior while backpress 1st keyboard hide after that activity.

I think you need to save editText data while activity destroy right?

while user come back to chat screen its shows old typed text right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code, and I can't comment yet, I will assume you're letting the onBackPressed do what it per default does, meaning that in your `onBackPressed()` method you have `super.onBackPressed();` , removing that line should solve the issue

**Edit**
Since you've updated your question with code, whatever is written after super.onBackPressed() will not be seen visually, as `super.onBackPressed()` goes back to the previous activity. Remove `super.onBackPressed()`, and handle the second back press with and if else statement

Comment: I removed the `super.onBackPressed();` ,but still the problem is we press back to dismiss the keyboard and then again press back and here the UI is changed .I want when the keyboard is dismissed on back pressed , the Ui should be handled here

Comment: I added the if statement and handled it .@Omar thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on activity, onBackPressed() function do the following,

```
// hide virtual keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_txtSearchText.getWindowToken(), 
                                      InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
```

Comment: the keyboard is dismissed when the user presses back , I want to do is when the keyboard is dismissed by user , some UI elements must be handled

Comment: @Neha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android